# Find and update certain columns of users information

Tags: php, mysql, session, sql-update

Within Mysql i have a database with a table called users. It stores the users: id, first_name, last_name, email, and hashed password (password).

I am trying to develop a piece of code which will update a certain users column of data through php. Within the php script it stores the session variables `$_SESSION['email']`  `$_SESSION['first_name']` and `$_SESSION['last_name']` which originate from a post request to update information on profile.php. I have spent hours trying to write a script (php) which will take `$_SESSION['email']` from the php code and query the mysql database what id it has (column), so i can then update the other information without blindly adding it to someone elses account.

here is some of the code on the page the customer sees

```
    <form action="updateinformation.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="first_name"  class="control-label">First Name <span class="required-field">*</span></label>
                                        <div class="has-feedback">
                                            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" id="first_name" />
                                            <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
..
...
....

</form>
```

here is the code i currently have which takes the post and turns it into a session variable (i deleted the code which doesnt work)

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $_POST['last_name'];

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Can someone please help!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

really it is easy, I'll do it in this way,

1) create a connectDB php file
2) into the form file I put an empty div called div_execute
3) Create a new php file called find_client_info.php witch takes an GET parameter like email to search for.
4) this find_client_info.php determine the values or actions using javascript at the end of file. (remember, we are not using ifrmes).
5) use jquery load for to load requested information,

sample:

```
 $("#div_execute").load("find_client_info.php?email=" + email);
```